# filling a blank between two bars - css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to move the blue bottom bar to paste it to the top blue bar, but I can't find how, any help please?

screenshot: http://hpics.li/1b82a29

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQzQD/)**

**HTML code :**

```
     <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <script language="javascript">
        var timeforhide;
        function showMenu(menuID) {
            clearTimeout(timeforhide)
            document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'visible'
        }
        function hideMenu(menuID) {
            timeforhide = setTimeout("didHideMenu()", 700)
        }
        function didHideMenu() {
            document.getElementById('menu').style.visibility = 'hidden'
        }
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <div>
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="/projetForum/accueil">Forum</a></li>

                <c:if test="${!empty utilisateur }">
                    <li><a href="/projetForum/profil">Profil</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/projetForum/deconnexion">Se déconnecter</a></li>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="${empty utilisateur}">
                    <li><a href="/projetForum/connexion">Se connecter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/projetForum/inscription">S'inscrire</a></li>
                </c:if>

                <li><a href="/projetForum/contactus">Nous contacter</a></li>
                <form method="post" action="<c:url value="/search"/>">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="recherche..." class="search"
                        required onFocus="showMenu('menu')" onBlur="hideMenu('menu')"/>
                </form>
            </ul>

            <table id="menu"
                style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; margin-left: 850px; width: 400px; color: #ffffff;">
                <tr>
                    <td>Recherche par :
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="sujet" checked />sujet</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="post" />post</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="choice" value="utilisateur" />utilisateur</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: It would be more helpfull to paste link to page where we can see it, not screenshot.

Comment: I haven't hosted my website yet

Comment: Well you could make jsfiddle...

Comment: @Cthulhu, okay here is the jsfiddle, can you show us how can u help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/UQzQD/3/

You should start with a good CSS reset. I used `*` selector to reset padding and margin in this example and it looks like what I think you want in FF, Chrome, and Safari.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

I fixed some errors in your HTML as well.

`language="javascript"` is obsolete, `<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/search"/>">` isn't valid.

Comment: that's it, thank you. Can you give me some reviews on my website (design, code) please?